# WPF Slow window resizing with borderless window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, optimization, mvvm

I have a borderless transparent (rounded corners) WPF Window.  It is a fairly complex app with a lot of dialogs that can be shown or hidden.  We do this via MVVM binding to the `Visibility` property using the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` which, as far as I am aware, set the visibility to `Visible` or `Collapsed` accordingly.

When I resize the window I get a significant lag in the drawing of the window that tends to leave content (borders, framework elements) behind (in that they dont follow the resize very fast).  So to clarify I have the main window and the content inside of it (the content is inside a border).  The main window will follow the mouse on resize accurately but the content will follow very slowly and will jerk.

I can't figure out what it is, can anyone offer any assistance? Obviously I am assuming that Collapsed dialogs are not resized (or relocated) when the window resizes.

Here is a little example of how we setup a dialog within the Main Window

```
<Grid x:Name="GlobalModalBackground" Visibility="{Binding ShowGlobalModalBackground, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=hidden}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Border CornerRadius="3" Background="#66000000" Opacity="{Binding ModalOpacity}" />
    <Grid>
        <local:About x:Name="AboutDialog" DataContext="{Binding AboutViewModel}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="300" Width="500"/>
        <!-- Other dialogs here -->
```

In this case, the AboutDialog itself will take care of showing itself or closing itself based on what its `ViewModel` is set to.

Comment: Actually, in WPF .Net 3.5 visual effects like `OpacityMasks`, `DropShadows` cause a poor render performance. For later versions, I'm not sure, if the improved the performance. So if it's easy turn those effects off and tell us, if it helps. :o)

Comment: I had a similar problem, but it turned out to be that my canExecute methods of button commands were too complicated.  Do you have these can execute methods in your miewmodel, if so, try to remove that logic and see if it helps.  Also, as always check for broken bindings.

Comment: @DHN We use drop shadows on most dialogs but only 1-2 are shown at any one point (and we use Effect not BitmapEffect, I've found removing them does help but It's kinda required for the design)

Comment: @JKing Does CanExecute really get hit on resize?

Comment: can execute gets hit on most ui related changes like mouse move etc.  put in a break point and you can see it is happening constantly.  Try commenting out your can execute logic and see if that helps.

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't... can't imagine why it should do either!

Comment: Do you have many grid columns and rows that adjust their size with a starred GridLength? This may be another factor that slows the resize.

Comment: We have many Grids with * based columns...

Comment: that might be an important factor, since it forces the layout manager to recalculate the size of many objects

Comment: @Daedalus How best to work around this when you need that functionality? I presume though that Grids that are not visible (parents are Collapsed) will not perform layouts?

Comment: I think (and hope) layout manager's code is optimized at best, so there might be no way to speed it up, but you can try search for some article that deals with the problem. Anyway, I think that to slow it that much you have really many columns and rows, or a dated hardware. In the first case, you might consider dividing your views. Maybe this link can help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx